# Update database field with BETWEEN operator using CakePHP and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

How to update all fields affected in MongoDB using cakephp. Say I have queried the Start and End Time. I want to update all the fields affected BETWEEN those time of an specific user.

```
<?php
  $stime = $this->data["User"]["sTime"]; //$stime = "2:29 PM";
  $etime = $this->data["User"]["eTime"]; //$eTime = "3:40 PM";
  $user = $this->data["User"]["affected_user"];
?>
```

All the fields within the start and end time will be affected. I would like to update a field called status and set it to "1". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [updateAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) statement to update multiple fields like.

```
<?php 

   // first of all convert the start time and end time in proper date format the use the statement like bellow.

   $this->ModelName->updateAll(array('status' => 1), array('time >=' => $stime, 'time <' => $etime));

?>
```

If you want to update multiple fields then you can specify like status in the same array. For more information checkout the [updateAll() documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) on the cakephp site.